# How to show image from the imagePath in swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiimageview

I have response from soap as image_path

> (self.posts.value(forKey: "image_path") as! [String])[indexPath.row]

This is my response

> "[http://sf.iipl.info/ImageCSharp.aspx?Location=C:\\infinityhost\\demo11.iipl.info\\data\\app\\user_location_photo\\8000034939_Resize\\&FileName=1_35f28e55-ca31-4918-8b41-9eb7f3070ace](http://sf.iipl.info/ImageCSharp.aspx?Location=C:%5C%5Cinfinityhost%5C%5Cdemo11.iipl.info%5C%5Cdata%5C%5Capp%5C%5Cuser_location_photo%5C%5C8000034939_Resize%5C%5C&FileName=1_35f28e55-ca31-4918-8b41-9eb7f3070ace)"

i cant convert this response to my url, i want to show this image in my tableViewCell

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        print((self.posts.value(forKey: "image_path") as! [String])[indexPath.row])

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AlllLocationTableViewCell

         let urlString = (self.posts.value(forKey: "image_path") as! [String])[indexPath.row] as String
        print("\(urlString)")



        let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: (self.posts.value(forKey: "image_path") as! [String])[indexPath.row])
        print(fileUrl as Any)



            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch

                self.Responseimage = UIImage(data: data!)!



        cell.LocationImage?.image = LocationImagView1
    return cell as UITableViewCell


    }
```

Comment: do you want to display image from URL or ImagePath?

Comment: @JagatDave From imagePath coz i have got that path from soap

Comment: Import SDWebImage library...And then try out my answer. Hope it will help to you.

Comment: I have answered how to load the image in your duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368512/image-path-not-convert-to-url-in-swift3/44369216#44369216

Answer (score 0):

First of all import `SDWebImage` library into your project then write the following code in your view controller as per your requirements.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ItemCell

    let urlStr = "https:\\images.com\image\12345.png".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

    print("URL :: \(urlStr!)");

    cell.imgItem.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlStr!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "item_placeholder"), options: [.refreshCached, .retryFailed, .allowInvalidSSLCertificates])

    }else{
        cell.imgItem.image = UIImage (named: "item_placeholder")
    }

    return cell
}
```